# Multiline function tables in lua

Tags: lua

I cannot seem to find any other online help about creating a table which contains functions which are multiline. For example, here is a snippit of code from the lua wiki.

```
action = {
  [1] = function (x) print(1) end,
  [2] = function (x) z = 5 end,
  ["nop"] = function (x) print(math.random()) end,
  ["my name"] = function (x) print("fred") end,
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
action = {
[1] = function blah()
more code here
end

[2] = function blahblah()
more code here
end

}
```

So how can I do so?

Comment: Just add a comma after each `end`.

Comment: Exactly as what done in the original. Inserting newlines into the original without editing anything else would have worked just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
action = {
  [1] = function (x)
    print(1)
  end,

  [2] = function (x)
    z = 5
  end,

  ["nop"] = function (x)
    print(math.random())
  end,

  ["my name"] = function (x)
    print("fred")
  end,
}
```

You are free to do that.

Comment: Would I be able to call the function using action[1] Also, if my function contained elseifs and ifs would this still work as wouldn't indentation be a problem?

Comment: @haws1290 Feel free to write anything you want there. There are no indentation issues in Lua.

Answer (score 0):

You can store in Lua almost every sourcecode with indentation when using the `[[]]` for datatype string.
Example

```
return {cat=[[return function(cat)
for line in io.lines(cat) do
 io.write(string.format('%s\n',line)):flush()
end 
end]],
chknx=[[-- chknx()
return function(func,...)
 local rc,rs=pcall(assert,func)
 if rc then return func(...) else return rc,rs end
end]],
cls=[[-- cls()
return function()
 os.execute('env -i TERM="xterm-256color" clear')
end]],
free=[[-- free()
return function()
local a=(collectgarbage('count')*1024)
print('Before: '..a..' Byte')
collectgarbage()
print('After: '..(collectgarbage('count')*1024)..' Byte')
a=a-collectgarbage('count')*1024
print('Freed: '..a..' Byte')
return a
end]],
shell=[[-- shell()
return function(shell)
if (type(shell)=='string') then
 os.execute(shell)
else
 os.execute('${SHELL} -l')
end
end]]}
```

This is a table with strings.
So every function can made available with: `funcname=load(string,'My Function')()`
The string "My Function" is used in traceback when an error occurs ;-)